# How to create list using first row of CSV file in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to create a list out of the first row - the column headers - of a csv file using python.  I put together this little script, but it prints two different lists.  The first item printed is the first row of the csv and the second thing printed in the second row.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv
import sys

with open('agentsFullOutput.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    print csvFile.next()
    field_names_list = []
    field_names_list = csvFile.next()
    print field_names_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `.next()` it'll move on to the next row in the file. So you'll only get the headers of the CSV file in the first `.next()` call:

```
import csv

with open('agentsFullOutput.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    field_names_list = reader.next()
```

Any subsequent `.next()` call will read the next row in the file so that would be a row of data.

Comment: `csvFile.next()` will read the line as a string and assign to `field_names_list`. perhaps you meant `reader.next()` or `csvFile.next().strip('\n').split(',')`

Comment: @HaleemurAli: actually yes, I meant `reader.next()` - thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thanks!  The only issue i'm having now is the list comprised of each individual character.  I've tried using the `excel` dialect, but it's not working.  `reader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='excel')`.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `next()` the next line from the file is `yielded` until the end of the file is reached.

In your code example, since you call `next()` twice, and in the second call you assign it to `field_name_list`, it assigns the 2nd row, not the first.

The following will assign the first row to the variable `field_names_list`.

```
with open('agentsFullOutput.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    field_names_list = next(reader)
```

Using `next(reader)` instead of `reader.next()` means that the code is portable to Python 3. On the 3+ series, the iterator's next() method has been renamed to `__next__()` for consistency.

Comment: I have tried the same with my CSV file which has about 16 elements seperated by ';' but Python is reading it as a single string in the list.... I mean the length of the list is 1 instead of 16. But from the second line it is considered as 16. I dont know why this is happening. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas library to read the first few lines from the huge dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("names.csv", nrows=1)
```

You can mention the number of lines to be read in the nrows parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
        with open(__csvfile) as csvFile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
```